# Get Multiple Values From Hash In Very Efficient Way

Tags: ruby, hash

My code is

```
a={"1"=>"adi","2"=>"amar","3"=>"rave","4"=>"sum"}
arr=["1","5","3"]
```

I want to  extract all values like this if array values exist in the hash

```
result =["adi","rave"]
```

without using any loop.Is it possible

Comment: you've changed `result`, thanks. Now an advice for future questions: don't name things `a` or `arr`, give meaningful names to data.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could do:

```
a.values_at(*arr).compact
# => ["adi", "rave"]
```

Comment: Please note that the splat operator (`*`) unwinds the array to the stack. So in case when your array is big you can end up with stack overflow